# Filebeat cant send data to logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have problem to send data from `*.log` file to logstash. This is filebeat configuration:

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/centos/logs/*.log  
filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: false
setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 3
setup.kibana:
output.logstash:
  hosts: "10.206.81.234:5044"
```

This is logstash configuration:

```
path.data: /var/lib/logstash
path.config: /etc/logstash/conf.d/*.conf
path.logs: /var/log/logstash
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.url: ["10.206.81.236:9200", "10.206.81.242:9200", "10.206.81.243:9200"]
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username: logstash_system
xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password: logstash
queue.type: persisted
queue.checkpoint.writes: 10
```

And this is my pipeline in  `/etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf`

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
    file{
        path => "/home/centos/logs/mylogs.log"
        tags => "mylog"
    }
    file{
        path => "/home/centos/logs/syslog.log"
        tags => "syslog"
    }
}
filter {
}
output {
    if [tag] == "mylog" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "10.206.81.246:9200", "10.206.81.236:9200", "10.206.81.243:9200" ]
            user => "Test"
            password => "123456"
            index => "mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }

    if [tag] == "syslog" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "10.206.81.246:9200", "10.206.81.236:9200", "10.206.81.243:9200" ]
            user => "Test"
            password => "123456"
            index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to have two separate outputs for `mylog` and `syslog`. At first, it works like this: everything was passed to `mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}` index even files from syslog. So I tried change second `if` statement to `else if`. It did not work so I changed it back. Now, my filebeat are not able to send data to logstash and I am receiving this errors:

```
2018/01/20 15:02:10.959887 async.go:235: ERR Failed to publish events caused by: EOF
2018/01/20 15:02:10.964361 async.go:235: ERR Failed to publish events caused by: client is not connected
2018/01/20 15:02:11.964028 output.go:92: ERR Failed to publish events: client is not connected
```

My second test was change my pipeline like this:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
    file{
        path => "/home/centos/logs/mylogs.log"
    }
}
filter {
    grok{
        match => { "message" => "%{IP:client} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:request} %{NUMBER:bytes} %{NUMBER:duration}" }
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "10.206.81.246:9200", "10.206.81.236:9200", "10.206.81.243:9200" ]
        user => "Test"
        password => "123456"
        index => "mylog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

If I add some lines to mylog.log file, filebeat will print the same ERR files but it is passed to logstash and I can see it in Kibana. Could anybody explain me why does it not work? What does those errors means?

I am using filebeat an  logstash version 6.1.

Comment: First, if you use filebeat to send logs to logstash, don't use logstash's `file input` for the same files. Simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: I do not understand the structure of config file. Should I have separate input {} for each file or how it should look like when I want to receive logs from different log files? How should I separate elasticsearch outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I make any mistake in english.

In the output section, you are using "tag" (note: is in singular) which doesn't exists. But changing this to "tags" will not work either because the field tags is an array and you will be comparing it to a string, so you should get the first item instead of getting the whole array and then compare. Try this:

```
if [tags[0]] == "mylog" { ......
```